# посчет дочерних элементов в сгенерированной разметке

Tags: javascript, html

у меня есть заготовка таблицы

```
<table id='table' style="width:40%">
        <thead id="modal_thead">

        </thead>
        <tbody id="modal_tbody">
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

в нее скриптом добавляются строки`var

```
    tbody=document.getElementById('modal_tbody')
    var str=10
    for (var c=0; c<str;c++){
                    var tr=document.createElement('tr')
tbody.appendChild(tr)
var td=document.createElement('td')
tbody.lastChild.appendChild(td)
alert(tbody.children.lenght) 
`
```

так вот , при вызове `alert` выдает `undefined`
почему и как сделать так, чтобы выдавал числовое значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
length
     ^--- проблема вот тут
```

Comment: точно, не заметил, спасибо, как время ожидание пройдет, приму ответ)